# What is the difference between systemd's "user" and "system" units/services?

Tags: systemd

As I'm kind of confused what the idea behind `systemd`'s `system` and `user` units or services is, I'd like to ask for an explanation.

Specifically I had thought *system units* are for units that are part of the vendor's operating system, while *user units* are for customer's local add-ons.

But it seems *user units* are handled differently by `systemd` (e.g. `systemctl daemon-reload` does not affect any user units, while the manual page claims: "*Reload the systemd manager configuration. This will rerun all generators (see systemd.generator(7)), reload all unit files, and recreate the entire dependency tree.*"), so it's not just some organizational structure, but a truly semantic one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`systemd` runs a service manager for the system and a service manager for logged in users. System units can only be started/stopped by UID 0 and system services are run as UID 0 (except if you set `User=`), the user units can be started/stopped by the respective user and user services are run as the respective user.

To talk to the service manager of the user, use `systemctl --user`. In your example, you would have to call `systemctl --user daemon-reload` in order to reload the user units.

Note that user units cannot depend on system units and vice versa.

Comment: So these are two independent mechanisms (user and system), accidentally implemented by the same program (systemd)? If so, only the "system" part is a replacement for "good old" `init`, while the "user" part is a new mechanism that didn't exist before? -- Maybe @segfault can add some more clarifying words on that...

Comment: "...*cannot depend on systemd units*..." should read "...*cannot depend on system units*...", I guess. Unfortunately such small edits are not allowed for me.